# Docker Filter with policy restart

Tags: docker

Is there any way to filter all containers with policy --restart=always ?

```
Server Version: 17.09.1-ce
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: With such little information it's unlikely you will get a good response. What context are you looking at? What are you trying to filter? What do you expect as the output etc.?

Comment: Hi Seth....I need something like docker ps --filter .... but that list all the containers that have --restart = always flag .... I need to list all the containers that will be automatically restarted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a start:

```
docker inspect --format "{{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}},{{.Name}},{{.Config.Image}},{{.State.Status}}" $(docker ps -aq) | column -s, -t | awk '{ if ($1 != "no") print }'
```